# Reputation change tracking goes wonky when a user is suspended

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

My profile page currently looks like this:

[image: reputation in profile page]

Note the -22,222 reputation. I'm certain this is due to me being suspended for a week about two weeks ago, but I'm not sure why it's a **negative** number.

Comment: Reputation is reset to 1 when a user is suspended. Thus, you (temporarily) lost all 22.2k of your reputation, which is why the system is showing a negative reputation change. That said, I still think this is a bug. A reputation change due to a suspension should not affect the reputation counter in the profile, *certainly* not once the suspension is over and the rep is restored.

Comment: I might have a similar issue with [the reputation change indicator in my profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQnMw.png) - it says -6266 because each time I downvote and flag an answer the value becomes more negative, but the counter is not updated when the answer is deleted. When I (rarely) get an upvote the counter becomes less negative as expected. I've definitely never had ~14000 reputation. I had a feeling it'd been reported as a bug before (but couldn't remember where) so haven't reported it.

Comment: These negative reputation points also works in the bubble. I haven't touched mine for a long time and it should read the reputation change from when I stopped touching it. But every time I downvote an Answer, the green bubble value goes down. It seems that if the Answer is deleted on the same UTC date, the value never goes back up. So my green bubble value has slowly just disappeared over time and only the green part is left (probably some privilege).

Comment: Yesterday I was on around -6600 but at some point the counter has reset, and I'm back to -8.

Comment: Related: [The counter on the Reputation tab does not reflect the net change in reputation since it was last visited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406093/1364007)