# Can the counter on the Reputation tab be modified to reflect the net change in reputation since it was last visited?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-history

A large part of my activities on Stack Overflow includes downvoting and flagging answers for deletion (which is partly why I have nearly 103k helpful flags). My Reputation tab says that I've lost 1272 reputation since I last visited it but my reputation graph (which doesn't show any appreciable decrease) does not concur:

[image]

In "[Reputation change tracking goes wonky when a user is suspended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403485/1364007)" [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte) said in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403485/reputation-change-tracking-goes-wonky-when-a-user-is-suspended#comment813052_403485) that:

> ... every time I downvote an Answer, the green bubble value goes down. It seems that if the Answer is deleted on the same UTC date, the value never goes back up.

which agrees with my own experiences.

Based on [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403485/reputation-change-tracking-goes-wonky-when-a-user-is-suspended#comment819110_403485) that I later posted on the above question

> Yesterday I was on around -6600 but at some point the counter has reset, and I'm back to -8.

I must have accidentally visited the Reputation tab around January 14th, clearing the counter (it was [at -6266](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQnMw.png) in early December). I have definitely not had ~8.9k reputation at any point - but I can well believe that I've downvoted and flagged *at least* 1272 answers in that period - I have raised 11,807 more helpful flags [since December 9th](http://web.archive.org/web/20201209172555/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364007/wai-ha-lee?tab=topactivity)).

In fact if I visit my [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), I infer that there have been

- 28 days with a net decrease in reputation, corresponding to a line of the form:

  ```
  -- 2021-02-08 rep -1    = 7544
  ```
- 18 instances where a post (question or answer) has been downvoted, corresponding to a line of the form:

  ```
  3  21087042 (-2)
  ```
- 29 instances where I have downvoted a post which has not been deleted, corresponding to a line of the form

  ```
  3  xxxxxxxx (-1)
  ```

or, in other words, nowhere near anything to account for a change in reputation of -1272.

---

**Update**: Since posting this question (as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report) I discovered that it is a cross-site duplicate of "[Reputation tab shows wrong change if downvoted answers were removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128310/284827)" from April 2012 on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/): [Nick Craver ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) posted [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128355/284827) which says:

> The value up top does not include changes from deleted posts…, this is by-design.
>
> We can't keep both totals, it'd be a recalc every time you toggle the "show removed" textbox and a change in trigger behavior depending on the preference (which is way, way, way more complicated than the current implementation), so we elected to show a total that reflects the default selection (not showing deleted posts, the same as it's always been).
>
> This may change later, if we can efficiently query this total and cache it (I'll take a look after my current project), but it's working as-intended at the moment.

I've reformulated the question into a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to account for the new information.

---

Could the Reputation tab be updated to reflect the *net* changes in reputation since it was last visited please? That would effectively fix the bug in "[Reputation change tracking goes wonky when a user is suspended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403485/1364007)", which is a symptom of this bug.

Obviously I don't know what the implementation of the Reputation tab looks like, but couldn't the reputation at the time the tab was last visited be stored somewhere, and the calculation adjusted to use that instead?

Comment: I just clicked on a ["Serial voting was reversed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwudm.png) event in my achievements tab which cleared the counter [from -3410](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faRwY.png).